# Do Primordials form a new Fetish Soul after Fetish Death?

Tags: lore, character-death, exalted

I'm wondering if Primordials reform their Fetish Souls after Fetish Death? On one hand, we've got Adrian turning into Adorjan after Lilike's death and there doesn't seem to be any mention of a new Fetish. On the other hand, I've read one or two mentions of the Fetish of the king of the Yozis being ritualistically slaughtered to form Malfeas, and we currently have Ligier, the Fetish Soul of Malfeas. So I wonder - do the Primordials reform their Fetishes after the old ones die, or do they only get one Fetish that they need to keep safe?

Comment: Any edition? 1, 2, 3?

Comment: @Trish Any edition

Answer (score 2):

Fetich souls don't reform per se, Fetich death throws the Primordial's entire soul hierarchy into disarray as it's lost it's core identity. A new Fetich soul will be created but it is implied that it is much more difficult to do and possibly requires the construction of an entirely new soul hierarchy to fit in line with the new identity. This alone is reason enough to keep the Fetich Soul safe.

The vast majority of Primordial/Yozi souls are left undocumented in the books and I don't recall any other Fetiches aside from Liger to be statted. The Fetich soul of the Ebon Dragon is mentioned in the Return of the Scarlet Empress but it's form, personality and power level are left entirely up to the GM.

Comment: Fetiches I've come across - Godhead (Autochton), Liger (Malfeas), Lilike (dead, Adrian), Daendels (Oramus), Ululaya (Kimbery), Kogami (Szoreny)